# What are the cons/pros of using ServiceMix vs Tomcat/WAR model?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, esb, apache-servicemix

I used to work for a while with bunch of Tomcat/WAR project deployments, but right now considering ESB model (i.e. SericeMix). What are the major pros/cons why should I be interested in switching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience.

ServiceMix, and OSGi in general, tends to overcomplicate your deployment model.

If you're not leveraging the benefits of OSGi, i.e. registering services, creating fragment bundles, etc., and you're doing what you would normally do with Tomcat, Jetty, etc., I would steer clear.

On the other-hand, if you're creating small, reusable bundles, and would like to introduce services like messaging, queuing, and other ESB-type functionality, ServiceMix, in my experience, has provided me with everything I would expect from an ESB.

I'm also using [OBR](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html), which greatly eases resolution of dependencies. With ServiceMix (Apache Karaf to be specific), there seems to be no way of *not* installing optional dependencies at this point in time, which has caused me grief, having to deal with package collisions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best of both worlds, I would look into Apache Camel.  It gives you a lot of the ESB functionality out of the box and can be deployed into any container including tomcat and servicemix.

ServiceMix can be frustrating because often times you are locked into certain version of projects like Camel, CXF and WSS4J.  You can manually upgrade the container to contain the versions that you need but this can be difficult.  However, the ServiceMix team with version 4.5.x has been a lot better about releasing minor versions to accommodate this.  When building a WAR, you just select your project versions/build/deploy.

The other thing about an OSGi container is that not all projects have OSGi ready bundles for you.  For example, in the past I needed Apache POI with specific functionality.  I had to go ahead and create the OSGi bundle on my own.

The advantages to the OSGi container are that the bundles you build are very small in size and not bloated with jar files and you can have different versions of bundles running at the same time.  However as Wulfgar says, if you don't need this functionality, it might be easier to stay clear of it.